# How can I give my follower a horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I buy a horse for my companion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38710/can-i-buy-a-horse-for-my-companion)

How can I can ease my follower's travels and get them a mount? It's common that I loose my follower because I ride and she not.

Comment: Hi @Leandro, unfortunately I'm voting to close your question as off-topic as per the [FAQ]. Mod-recommendations have the same issues as game-recommendations do, in that there's no one single answer you can accept, they lend them themselves to inaccurate voting schemes (people upvoting what they like rather than what constitutes a quality answer), and they're very subjective. We can't build a comprehensive mod list in our engine, as it's not viable. Please feel free to stop by our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) if you'd like instead.

Comment: ok, thanks fae! Well, I asked because i read first that post and I can't found a mod to solve or answer that one. But you re right about the stack exchange schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently not, but fast traveling or going through a cave or door will quickly bring your follower to your side.